# Quick Question: Wireless Belt Packs and Receivers

Tags: wireless, microphone, lavalier, lapel, transmitter

Hi everyone,

I need a really quick answer to this question if you don't mind:

I'm researching a future purchase for a production company that records short films and documentaries that have a wide variety of unprofessional talent and very impromptu camera angles and frames, thus the necessity of a really simple and easy-to-set-up but professional quality (if possible...) sound system.

Unfortunately, most of these shoots will not have the budget to hire professional sound men but I will be training up certain people on how to use these mics and transmitters for the production company, and I have a very keen vested interest on how these sound because I'm the one who will end up mixing these recordings most likely.

So, in your professional opinion, what is a good quality mic + transmitter combination I can research further that fits the above criteria (if any)?

EDIT: Right now we own hoards of Tram and COS-11 mics, and I like the sound of those. I'm mainly concerned more about what belt-packs and transmitter/receivers as well as recorders used in this scenario.

Thanks very much in advance for your input. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the budget to work with a Lectrosonic's 400 Series, then just do it. It's the best thing I've ever worked with on a production before and well worth the money. I've had a pair of Sennheiser G3 100's for a year now and they've worked pretty well for me. If you've got Tram's and COS-11 mics that will work with these transmitters, I'm sure it'll be enough to get the job done and they're much cheaper then the Lectrosonics.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of service! 

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the Sennheiser ew 100 ENG G3 kit we use them a lot and they just keep working.  For simple shoots just plug them straight into the camera using the hotshoe mount.

http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_wireless-microphone-systems_broadcast-eng-film_ew-100-g3_021118

Answer (score 1):

I must say I'm very fond of Lectrosonic's transmitters/receivers! Built like tanks and very trusty in my opinion!

The last year I've worked very much with the combo Lectrosonic and DPA, and for the first time when working with lavalier, though I still very much prefer boom, I'm fairy satisfied with what I got!

Answer (score 1):

i would say if the gear is to be used by mostly inexperienced people, then maybe the lav is not the way to go.
i would think it would be easier to boom.